# Where can I get word lists for Indian languages, specifically Hindi and Tamil?

Tags: data-request, language

Is there a way to get word lists for Indian languages (specifically Tamil and Hindi), even for commercial use? It is for a game I am developing

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is often refereed to as corpus in a scientific context. If you would like separated words then you can programmatically parse the data and generate lists (this is a simple task in Python). Here are a few useful links:

- For a Hindi corpus:

  - [uni-leipzig-hindi-corpus](https://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/en?corpusId=hin_news_2011)
  - [iitk-Hindi-corpus](http://home.iitk.ac.in/~prasant/HindiCorpus/corpus.html)
  - [sketchengine-Hindi-corpus](https://www.sketchengine.eu/hindiwac-hindi-corpus/)
- For a Tamil corpus:

  - [tamil-text-corpora](https://www.sketchengine.eu/corpora-and-languages/tamil-text-corpora/)
  - [Tamil Monolingual Text Corpus ILCI-II](https://tdil-dc.in/index.php?option=com_download&task=showresourceDetails&toolid=1891&lang=en)
  - [tamil-corpus-bank](http://www.tamilvu.org/en/tamil-corpus-bank)
  - [uni-leipzig-Tamil-corpus](https://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/en?corpusId=tam_newscrawl_2011)
  - [Tamil-corpora](https://mailman.uib.no/public/corpora/2016-September/025221.html)

Answer (score 0):

In case, if you have not seen this sites so what about this ?

https://www.omniglot.com/index.htm

http://mylanguages.org/